# Placing Multiple Buttons to a Relative Layout without a Grid in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to add multiple buttons to a layout programmatically. 
However, count of buttons is different every time and I just want them to placed next to each other with a wrap content width. After a line is filled, it should go to next line and continue that way.

What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: why not LinearLayout?

Comment: Hmm, actually LinearLayout is also okay for me. But, how will i spread multiple buttons next to each other for multiple rows without specifying count of buttons per row beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout verticalLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

while(isActive) {
LinearLayout horziontalLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
horziontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    add buttons here..
//Example Button button = new Button(context);
//horziontalLayout.addView(button);
verticalLayout.addView(horziontalLayout);

isActive = false // when youe done filling up buttons..
 }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks.

However, Will I be able to add arbitrary number of buttons this way? Because it looks like that i have to decide how many buttons that i will add to horizantalLayout?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way should be having a vertical LinearLayout in wich you add multiple horizontal LinearLayout

```
//vertical one
LinearLayout vlinear = new LinearLayout(this);
vlinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams vlinearParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
vlinear.setLayoutParams(vlinearParams);
parentgroup.addView(vlinear);

//horizontal lines
for (int i=0;i<numlines){
    LinearLayout hlinear = new LinearLayout(this);
      hlinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LayoutParams vlinearParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
hlinear.setLayoutParams(hlinearParams);
vlinear.addView(hlinear);
///add the loop for adding cells
for...
hlinear.addView(cell);
    }
```